# Password protect a page without using the membership system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, password-protection

I've got a ASP.NET MVC 5 web application an it runs quite well.

It's a website with a login feature but only for an admin use (me).
The authentification runs with the membership system (Identity) and it's ok.

In other hand, users (anonymous users) can create posts in this website.
When they create it, they fill in a password field and this password is associated to the post.

The goal is that this post can be edited or deleted only by those who know the relative password.

There is no authentification (no cookie), I just want the edit and the delete pages be password protected.

Question:
How do I build my view and my controller to add a form and validate it before displaying the protected content?

I'm lost here, I don't found any help on Internet since this case is not commun.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit action method add an extra parameter named password and get the password from user. Then check if password is correct let user edit the post. In post back method again check the password and if password is correct accept editing. consider this example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string password)
{
     if(_myPostManager.IsValidPassword(id,password))
     {
         var post=_myPostManager.Get(id);

         return View(new EditPostViewModel
             {ID=post.ID, Content=post.Content, Password=password});
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Error");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditPostViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // double check password
        if(_myPostManager.IsValidPassword(model.ID,model.Password))
        {
            // save your data to DB
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The view model:

```
public EditPostViewModel
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
    // your other members
}
```

and view:

```
@model MyNamespace.EditPostViewModel
// inside your form element add a hidden filed and put password here
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Password)
// your other fields
```

You could also put password in session instead of passing to view. Or encrypt password and send encrypted password to view.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it and I have a question concerning the GET and POST methods to the Edit page.
Your solution works well but the password is sent via the GET method and is visible in the adress bar.

Do you think a good solution might be that the Edit action just return the password form, and the EditPost action returns the password  form if the password is wrong, or the Post Edit form if it's right?

Comment: I did it and it's the right way to go. It works, thanks.